# How to rewrite multiple parameter URL in .htaccess and core PHP to make it seo friendly

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am working on a blog,
And my current blogpost URL is looking like this

```
https://myblog.example/blog-inner.php?url=my-awesome-life
```

Now I want to rewrite this URL to look like

```
https://myblog.example/blog/catogory/my-awesome-life
```

Please note: we have a single category for each blog.

So how can we rewrite its URL in `.htaccess` and what are the procedure to display this blog perfectly?

Answer (score 2):

Here is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/catogory/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ blog-inner.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/catogory/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ blog-inner.php?url=$1&something=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try it like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the specific question being asked and requires further explanation. You can't just throw a generic front-controller pattern as the solution and expect it to stick.

Comment: No, it's work you can hide extinction using .htaccess that's helping in SEO for on-page SEO, you can also use custom routing for get specific URL segment

Comment: “No, it's work” - only by refactoring the rest of the application, which you’ve not explained in your answer.